# How to execute file on pendrive with FAT file system?

Tags: usb, permissions, usb-drive

I want to execute file ex from my memory stick with FAT file system. I typed:

```
/media/user/844E-0486$ sudo chmod 777 ex
```

However still I haven't got permission to execute it.

```
/media/user/844E-0486$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 lut 18 17:46 ex
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 8192 lut 18 17:44 System Volume Information
```

Is there any way to run it?

Comment: FAT does not support permissions, you have to set ownership and permissions when you mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't , because FAT FileSystem doesn't supports permissions.

Instead of `./ex` you can use `sh ex`

Comment: It's not known whether `ex` is a shell script. Also, even if it is a shell script, it may be a Bash or other non-DASH script, in which case that shell should be used instead.